# Panel with Tabs - How to add title?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking at this and wondering how I could pull the tabs to the right and still add a title? I've tried playing around with it but I end up breaking everything.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try this: to element with class "panel-heading" add class "clearfix". Then, to `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` css float: right; or class "pull-right".

Answer (score 0):

This will reverse the order of the tabs, but as long as you are aware of that and reverse the order you intend them to be displayed in, you'll be fine.

```
.nav-tabs>li {
  float: right;
}
```